# SSRS 2005 page break per report

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I have a specific type report that I need to generate multiple copies of.  What I want to do is pass a string of report IDs to SSRS and generate all of the individual reports (let call them subreports) with those IDs in one master report with each subreport on a new page.  I've already tried making a subreport and placing it in a table with grouping.  This worked the closest so far.  It gave me all the pages I needed, but it generated the report for the first ID number over and over.  Is there anyway to do this or am I gonna have to jump through a lot of hoops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are passing the string of report IDs to a parameter on the master report, I think using a table and subreport should work.  You'll need a way to split out the report IDs using a dataset on the master report and return them one per row (so you can pass each report ID individually to the subreport via the details row of the table).

I was going to recommend a table-valued parameter for this, but since they don't exist in SQL Server 2005 check out [Arrays and Lists in SQL Server 2005 by Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html) for a few other options.